# Incorrect behavior of gravity attributes of new Android Toolbar's child views

Tags: android, toolbar, android-appcompat

I am trying to implement custom layout inside new Toolbar widget provided by new AppCompat library according to this sketch

[image]

So I am trying to add new Layout component inside Toolbar and set it's gravity attributes to **bottom|center_horizontal**. But it seems like this attribute completely doesn't matter and my child layout always positioned on the vertical center of Toolbar and to left of hamburger icon.

[image]

My XML-layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/title">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="176dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_menu"
        android:layout_width="264dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="?android:colorBackground"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any ideas how to achieve correct alignment of child views inside Toolbar?

Comment: it's an alternative to Lorem Ipsum)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT:** `android:gravity` defines how to align the **inner** content of the view (text alignment, child views, etc.), not the alignment of the view in its parent view.

change

```
android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

to

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```